# Novel with a room with model sailing ship bifurcated into metal and wood

Tags: story-identification

I read this book many years ago and remember no other details, and I can find nothing on the web.  The protagonist sneaks into an attic, only to discover the room is perfectly split in half—half the room is made of normal organic materials like wood, and the other half is entirely metal.  In the center of the room is a model of a sailing ship, perfectly split so that one side is wood and the other side metal.  It was not a short story. Robots were involved.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: What's particularly science-fiction or fantasy about it?

Comment: If whatever item you get into that attic bifurcates, separates into organic and inorganic parts, it would certainly count as scifi or fantasy.

Comment: @jo1storm that is correct.

Comment: There needs to be more detail of what exactly makes it scifi or fantasy, not just agreeing with something in the comments. It needs to be in the question. Depending on the type of robot, it's not explicitly sci-fi...

Comment: @Edlothiad - How could a robot that transforms wood into metal not be sci-fi? Such a technology doesn't exist today, aren't advanced technologies that go beyond what's possible today by definition science fiction? Are you suggesting the robot might have used magic?

Comment: @Hypnosifl - A magic-using robot would be very firmly on-topic

Comment: @BMF it’s not immediately clear from the details in the question itself. However, from the details in the comments given by jo1storm and confirmed by the OP it clearly is on topic. Personally I think the comment details should really be in the question itself.

Comment: @Hypnosifl how did you garner that much detail from the three word sentence of "Robots were involved". In what? The story as a whole? The assembly of the attic? Guarding the attic? The process of converting things that cross the threshold from organic to in-? As pet dogs? Cleaning staff? Catering? Did the robots convert from wood to metal? You've attacked my comment for more details from quite the strong assumption based on a seemingly randomly placed three word sentence.

Comment: @BMF It is not the job of the users here to sort out details of the story. Users who answer Story ID questions are expected to _identify_ stories from details provided by the original poster. It is why we have the extensive checklist provided by Valorum and so often ask for more details. As it stands this question could quite easily be the description for a modern art installation. There's nothing fantastical. If there is a threshold that converts things or these mentioned robots have tools to convert things etc then sure. But as it stands without adding your own details, no, it isn't clear.

Comment: @Edlothaid - "robots were involved" pretty heavily implies that robots caused the bifurcation of the room, and then the response to jo1storm clarifies that was indeed the implication in case it wasn't obvious. Are you objecting just to the fact that it says "robots were involved" rather than "robots caused it", even though the latter would merely spell out something that was implied but not actually add new details that would help people to identify the story? If so that seems overly nitpicky, and I don't think the site's rules actually support the idea that using implication is bad.

Comment: @Edlothiad Yeah, I think I see that now. I was looking to see whether the information was broad making the question unanswerable. I think the OP probably conveyed the most memorable parts of the story, things that others who know the story would recognize. But saying "robots were involved" doesn't automatically root it in the relevant genres.

Comment: @Hypnosifl the sentence “robots were involved” comes after “it wasn’t a short story” it’s completely disjointed from the division of the room. And jo1storm’s comment came 10 hours _before_ the edit. I’m not objecting to any facts, I don’t know how you came to that conclusion. I’m saying if you read this post as is, it’s a description of what could be a modern art installation, information that it wasn’t a short story (so could be an art installation) and that robots were involved (not how just that they were). None of these say “yes this story is explicitly SFF”.

Comment: @BMF I certainly don’t think it’s too broad, there are just no details in the post that put it into an on-topic genre. Even the comment says the idea that a “room that bifurcates anything that enters it into organic and inorganic parts is on-topic” is true. It doesn’t say whether it applies. Sure benefit of the doubt could be applied, and I probably would’ve applied it if I saw this in the close queue. But from the re-open queue? Not enough there for me. But the community decided otherwise.

Comment: @Edlothiad - Maybe you missed it, but the question says at the beginning "I read this book many years ago" so I think it's clear enough that "it wasn't a short story" meant it was a novel-length fiction as opposed to a short story collection (or something completely different, like an art installation), and given this context it seems like a clear implication that robots were involved in the plot of the book, presumably related to the bifurcation of the room and not just a random non sequitur. Again, nothing in the rules of the site says you have to spell out natural implications like this.

Comment: @Hypnosifl No I didn't miss it, I'm just raising the argument that none of the details in the post make it specifically on-topic. The robots certainly were involved in the plot. You've made the assumption that they somehow convert the room between materials from them just being mentioned. If the sentence had been placed right after the description of the room, sure the implication is that robots had something related to that. Maybe as guardians or organisers, or as bifurcaters. But it comes at the end, after the point has moved on, almost as an after thought, the implication is not natural.

Answer (score 4):

Since you remember so little, I am going to suggest that this may be an amalgam of more than one story, with one of the stories being *[The Ship of Ishtar](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0601941h.html)* (1924) by Abraham Merritt.  What is distinctive is the presence of a model of a sailing ship, split in half with decks made of two different materials.

> There was a sharp crackling. The block split. From the break pulsed a radiance as of rosy pearls and with it wave after wave of the fragrance —no longer questing, no longer wistful nor supplicating.
>
> Jubilant now! Triumphant!
>
> Something was inside the block! Something that had lain hidden there since Sargon of Akkad, six thousand years ago!
>
> The carillons of jade rang out again. Sharply they pealed, then turned and fled back the endless corridors up which they had come. They died away; and as they died the block collapsed; it disintegrated; it became a swirling, slowly settling cloud of sparkling dust.
>
> The cloud whirled, a vortex of glittering mist. It vanished like a curtain plucked away.
>
> Where the block had been stood—a ship!
>
> It floated high on a base of curving waves cut from lapis lazuli and foam- crested with milky rock crystals. Its hull was of crystal, creamy and faintly luminous. Its prow was shaped like a slender scimitar, bent backward. Under the in-curved tip was a cabin whose seaward sides were formed, galleon fashion, by the upward thrust of the bows. Where the hull drew up to form this cabin, a faint flush warmed and cloudy crystal; it deepened as the sides lifted; it gleamed at last with a radiance that turned the cabin into a rosy jewel.
>
> In the center of the ship, taking up a third of its length, was a pit; down from the bow to its railed edge sloped a deck of ivory. The deck that sloped similarly from the stern was jet black. Another cabin rested there, larger than that at the bow, but squat and ebon. Both decks continued in wide platforms on each side of the pit. At the middle of the ship the ivory and black decks met with an odd suggestion of contending forces. They did not fade into each other. They ended there abruptly, edge to edge; hostile.

The main character, Kenton, is drawn by magic onto the cursed ship and back into the ancient world where it plies the seas.  He travels back and forth from the ship to the present several times.  (The novel was serialized, and the sections tended to end with Kenton returning to modern times.  In my personal opinion, the first part of the story to be published is significantly better than the rest.)

Comment: Unfortunately thats not it.  It definitely involved robots.

Comment: @qazwsx If not, then it may have been an intentional homage to *The Ship of Ishtar*.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you stated that it's not a short story, I'm going to suggest [*The Tunnel Under The World*](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45822) by Fred Pohl, a novelette (available [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/31979/31979-h/31979-h.htm)) in which the main character finds something odd in his basement:

> Where the old trunk had been, the cellar floor gleamed oddly bright.
> He inspected it in the flashlight beam. It was metal!
>
> "Son of a gun," said Guy Burckhardt. He shook his head unbelievingly.
> He peered closer, rubbed the edges of the metallic patch with his
> thumb and acquired an annoying cut—the edges were sharp.
>
> The stained cement floor of the cellar was a thin shell. He found a
> hammer and cracked it off in a dozen spots—everywhere was metal.

A boat is involved:

> The biggest surprise was the upside-down boat hull that blocked the
> rear half of the cellar, relic of a brief home workshop period that
> Burckhardt had gone through a couple of years before. From above, it
> looked perfectly normal. Inside, though, where there should have been
> thwarts and seats and lockers, there was a mere tangle of braces,
> rough and unfinished.
>
> "But I built that!" Burckhardt exclaimed, forgetting his thumb. He
> leaned against the hull dizzily, trying to think this thing through.

As are robots

> All the evidence had been before him. The automatized factory, with
> its transplanted minds—why not transplant a mind into a humanoid
> robot, give it its original owner's features and form?